# Problema al utilizar INNER JOIN con dos tablas

Tags: sql, select, tablas

Estoy haciendo un INNER JOIN entre dos tablas para mostrar todos los datos de la tabla cursos y el nombre del profesor de la tabla profesores a través del ID_profesor.

Las tablas tienen un campo en común: la tabla cursos(ID_profesor) y la tabla profesores(ID_profesor), este es la primary.

**Cursos**

- ID_cursos
- nombre
- ID_profesor
- carga_horaria
- descripcion

**Profesores**

- ID_profesor
- nombre
- CI
- edad
- direccion
- pais

Yo lo que quiero es que al mostrar todos los datos del curso, que aparezca el nombre del profesor y no el número del id.

Este el el select:

```
SELECT profesores.*, cursos.* 
FROM profesores 
INNER JOIN cursos on profesores.ID_profesor = cursos.ID_curso
```

Comment: Hola, que es lo que has avanzado, y cual es el resultado, para a partir de ahi apoyarte.

Comment: Te podemos ayudar, pero agrega la consulta que hiciste

Comment: Este el el select: SELECT profesores.*, cursos.* FROM profesores INNER JOIN cursos on profesores.ID_profesor = cursos.ID_curso

Comment: pero no me muestra ningún registro en la tabla html.

Comment: @DiegodelosSantos también especifica que base de datos usas

Answer (score 0):

cuando haces un inner join, tienes que igualar o validar que ambas columnas sean las mismas.

```
SELECT profesores.*, cursos.* FROM profesores INNER JOIN cursos on profesores.ID_profesor = cursos.ID_profesor
```

Si tienes en las 2 tablas el ID_profesor , pues usalas para que te traiga los resultados.

Comment: Ahora si, gracias

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona por que estás tratando de vincular 2 entidades por 2 columnas que no están ni directamente relacionadas y que tampoco puedes asegurar que los datos de un extremo se correspondan con el del otro extremo.

Lo que debes igualar son la llave primaria del profesor contra la llave foránea del curso, ahi si existe la relación y cuando dicha llave (*primaria*) esté o exista en al menos un registro del otro extremo (*llave foránea*); entonces comenzará a devolverte renglones con valores.

Esto te ayudará a encontrar que cursos tiene asociados cada profesor por medio de su id en la tabla cursos.

Modificala así:

```
Profesores.ID_profesor = Cursos.ID_profesor
```

**Referencias**

- Revisa [justo aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) la sintaxis que debes aplicar.
- Acá puedes leer sobre [llaves foráneas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)